# Struts to spring Conversion- replacement of struts jsp tags

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I'm working on Struts to Spring  conversion. I m using Spring MVC. I cannot find the replacement for below struts jsp tags in spring.

- html:cancel
- List item
- html:javascript
- bean:define
- logic:iterate
- bean:write
- logic:empty
- logic:notEmpty

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Spring MVC privides tags for binding and displaying form elements and displaying form errors out of the box. For other stuff (like logic, formatting, output, seeting bean values etc) you can use standard JSTL tags. For e.g., as a replacement of logic:empty you can use *c:if*. For iterating you can use *c:forEach*. The basic idea is that in both the MVC framework (Struts or Spring MVC) , the controller saves some attributes in scope (usually request) and then on the JSP page you can use JSTL tags to do whatever you want. For something like html:cancel, you can implement it using a mix of Jquery / JSTL. You will have to understand what the corresponding tag in struts actually does and implement it using Spring MVC for those cases. There is no direct replacement of tags as this is not naturally possible as both handle things differently.